# React - useCallback throwing error on renderProps function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I'm passing renderProps function in the props. i want to wrap it with useCallback, so the optimised child component will no re-render on the function creation.

when wrapping the function with useCallback i get this error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

none of the above applies to my situation.

```
renderCell = React.useCallback((
    {
      events,
      popperPlacement,
      popperStyle,
      time
    }
  ) => {
    const { localeToggle } = this.state;
    const { weekStarter, isTimeShown } = this.props;
    const eventsListPopperStyle = utils.isWeekFirst(time, weekStarter) ||
      utils.isWeekSecond(time, weekStarter) ? { left: '-17% !important' } : { left: '17% !important' };
    return (
      <MonthlyCell
        events={events}
        isTimeShown={isTimeShown}
        popperPlacement={popperPlacement}
        popperStyle={popperStyle}
        time={time}
        eventsListPopperStyle={eventsListPopperStyle}
      />
    )
  }, [])
```

Comment: by any chance, the component that has `renderCell` method is a class component? If so, you can't use the hooks in it.
Note: By the looks of the given snippet, I think your component is a class component.

Comment: @pritam yes it is, you right. is there a way to achieve the same behaviour with a class component ?

Comment: I'd rather refactor my parent component to a functional component and keep same implementation of useCallback. Otherwise you could look into `React.memo` and use that for your child component to avoid re-rendering.

Comment: @pritam Yea that's what i do. The child has memo, the problem is that because of the render props it always re-render. Currently, i solved it by adding areEqual to the memo. It check the prevProps vs nextProps, and disregard function type props.

Comment: Yeah that's right. Memo works for a level deep. If you have multi level data passed down to child or a render prop, you'd need explicit deep checks as part of your memo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because hooks doesn't work inside class components, the error was thrown.
I managed to find a work around by providing the second parameter for the React.memo. in the function i provided, i compare the prevProps and nextProps, and when the prop is a function i disregard it and return true.
it might not work for everyone because sometime the function do change, but for situations when it's not, it's ok.

```
const equalizers = {
  object: (prevProp, nextProp) => JSON.stringify(prevProp) === JSON.stringify(nextProp),


  function: () => true, // disregarding function type props


  string: (prevProp, nextProp) => prevProp === nextProp,
  boolean: (prevProp, nextProp) => prevProp === nextProp,
  number: (prevProp, nextProp) => prevProp === nextProp,
}

export const areEqualProps = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  for (const prop in prevProps) {
    const prevValue = prevProps[prop];
    const nextValue = nextProps[prop];
    if (!equalizers[typeof prevValue](prevValue, nextValue)) { return false; }
  }
  return true
}

export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqualProps)
```